# LocalStorage to check how many times a modal is open

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage, counter

I have an uncertain amount of modals in my page, all determined by an specific ID. What I'm doing is checking how many times a modal gets open, and then, by using a counter, I reach a certain limit.

This limit is taken from a JSON file and then compared with the amount of times the modal has been opened.

But here's the catch. I need to save this data (the one concerning the openings) into LocalStorage, so everytime I close my browser the data remains.

As you can see, I have a "testObject" variable created in LocalStorage, this one's equal to the alertCounter. Then I compare it to my ShowingLimit variable (extracted from the JSON file) and that shows me an alert.

The question's simple. How do I keep the data from rebooting?

```
var alertCounter = 0;
$("#" + modalName + "").on("shown.bs.modal", function(e){
    alertCounter++;
    localStorage.testObject = alertCounter;
    if(localStorage.testObject == showingLimit){
        alert("We've reached the limit");
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
 if(localStorage.testObject){ //Is there any testObject?
         if(+localStorage.testObject >= showingLimit )//is equal to the limit
           {
             alert("We've reached the limit");//or whatever
           }
           else{
                +localStorage.testObject++; //+ 1
                }

         }else{
               localStorage.testObject = 1; //first time
               }
```

Note that the + is to cast as integer, because is stored as string.